# How to ensure uniqueness of readability of nested lists over some alphabet $S$?

Tags: definition, formal-languages

Here is something that has been bothering me. Let me just give an example to show what I mean. Consider the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$. $(a,b,c)$ is a list from this alphabet. $(a,b,(a,b))$ is a nested list from this alphabet. However, here is the catch: Secretly, $c$ is actually equal to $(a,b)$. So now, there is some confusion as to whether $(a,b,c)$ is a regular list or a nested list. My question really is, given a set $S$ of symbols, how does one pass to an isomorphic copy $S'$ and work with nested lists over $S'$ rather than $S$ itself, so that confusions like that don't occur, and uniqueness of readability of nested lists is ensured? I am interested in such a set-theoretic construction of $S'$.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "list" and "nested list": you are asking us: how can I disguise the elements of a set so that none of them is a "list"? But how can we answer that without knowing what you mean by a "list"?

Comment: @RobArthan By list, I mean a finite sequence, that is, a function from the set of positive integers from $1$ to $n$, to the alphabet.

Comment: OK. So it looks like your alphabet $S$ is finite and can be enumerated as $s_1, s_2, \ldots s_n$, for some $n$. if you use the Kuratowski definition of pairs, the von Neumann definition of integers and use those to represent finite functions on integer intervals $1 \ldots n$, what can go wrong if you replace $s_i \in S$ by $i \in S' = \{1, \ldots n\}$?

Comment: @RobArthan The alphabet does not have to be finite. For example, we can have the alphabet consisting of the set of natural numbers.  In that case, of course, any list of natural numbers (meaning the function which is the list) will not be onto. The set of all finite sequences with elements in the set $S$ is commonly called the Kleene closure of $S$.

Comment: So if the alphabet is not finite, what goes wrong if you replace $S$ by its cardinal? My point here is: what work have you done to investigate the possible issues with the usual representations of the concepts in question?

Comment: @RobArthan So, I guess, replacing $S$ by $Card(S)$ is the set-theoretic construction.

Comment: I wasn't claiming to have checked all the details. But that is the construction I would investigate first. If it doesn't work out, then it shouldn't be too problematic to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For operations on nested lists to be well-defined, you need a clear definition of what is a list and what isn't (or equivalently, what is an atomic element and what isn't). This criterion should be semantic as opposed to syntactic, so that it does not depend on how you refer to the object (e.g. as "$c$" vs. as "$(a,b)$").

In type theory and programming, we can use a [sum type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) with a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) construct to establish the disjoint cases for atoms and sublists. The analogous construction in set theory is a [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union).

To flesh this out: we can recursively define a nested list over alphabet $S$ to be a tuple that has one of the following forms:

- $(0,a)$ where $a\in S$
- $(1,x_1,\dots,x_n)$ where each $x_i$ is a nested list over $S$.

The idea here is that we have *tagged* our objects to indicate whether they represent atoms or sub-lists in order to avoid any dependence on the internal structure of the elements of $S$. The shape $(a,b,(a,b))$ is represented by $(1,(0,a),(0,b),(1,(0,a),(0,b)))$, whereas the shape $(a,b,c)$ is represented by $(1,(0,a),(0,b),(0,c))$. Notice that these are different even if $c=(a,b)$, or even if $a,b,c$ happen to be nested lists themselves. The tags, not the letters, are what determine the nesting shape.

Comment: The OP is asking how to obtain that clarity of *representation*. I.e., how to ensure that the stipulations of your first paragraph are achieved.

Comment: I see. My second paragraph alluded to how that is done, and I've just added a more explicit explanation.

Comment: Despite the tick, this does not answer the question as stated: the question asks for a construction that gives a copy $S'$ of $S$ such that the usual constructions of lists won't give rise to a problem, your construction does not work like that.

Comment: @RobArthan Yeah, I guess I addressed the spirit of the question with a solution that was not of the requested form. A solution of that form would depend on the set-theoretic implementation details of tuples; presumably we'd construct $S'$ by "wrapping" each element of $S$ in some clever junk whose set-theoretic shape can never be that of a tuple. I think the algebraic type-motivated approach (to the general problem of ensuring that data representations are unambiguous) is more robust.

Comment: Actually, the approaches are related. The "wrapper junk" serves the purpose of my "0 tag".

Comment: Karl: I appreciate that thinking in terms of types makes this all much cleaner, but first-order set theory is not a typed system. I think if you just replace $S$ by its cardinal you get something that works with the usual representations, but I agree that this depends on set-theoretic implementation details. It is also worth pointing out that you are assuming the axiom of foundation (and I probably am too).